# Return Table from Google Sheets in Google Sites Using Options from 3 Select Lists

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheet that I want to let users query in a Google Site by picking three options in select lists and to have it return the results as a table.

My sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f5WBP_vizrCw27fSA6yc0EEN_twmdC-PoXZhm_PSNH0/).

I have tried a few setQuery examples but not getting much luck since almost all examples return a chart which I do not want, just a table of what is in my sheet. Below is what I embed into my Google Site (minus the CSS). The function `text()` is just a test to make sure I was capturing people's choices. So as you will see this code does not have the Google functions in the script yet, that's what I am missing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Search For Your Zodiac Twin</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script>
    function text(){
      var s = document.getElementsByName('sun')[0];
      var stext = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
      var m = document.getElementsByName('moon')[0];
      var mtext = m.options[m.selectedIndex].text;
      var r = document.getElementsByName('rising')[0];
      var rtext = r.options[r.selectedIndex].text;
      document.getElementById("resulttext").innerHTML='Instagram users who match your signs are:';
      document.getElementById("resulttable").innerHTML='Your sun sign is ' + stext + ', your moon is ' + mtext + ', and your rising is ' + rtext;
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sun" style="color: #ffc107ff">Sun</label>
        <br>
        <select name="sun" class="form-control-sun" id="sun">
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Your Sun</option>
          <option value="Aquarius">Aquarius</option>
          <option value="Aries">Aries</option>
          <option value="Cancer">Cancer</option>
          <option value="Capricorn">Capricorn</option>
          <option value="Gemini">Gemini</option>
          <option value="Leo">Leo</option>
          <option value="Libra">Libra</option>
          <option value="Pisces">Pisces</option>
          <option value="Sagittarius">Sagitarrius</option>
          <option value="Scorpio">Scorpio</option>
          <option value="Tarus">Taurus</option>
          <option value="Virgo">Virgo</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="moon" style="color: #2196f3ff">Moon</label>
        <br>
        <select name="moon" class="form-control-moon" id="moon">
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Your Moon</option>
          <option value="Aquarius">Aquarius</option>
          <option value="Aries">Aries</option>
          <option value="Cancer">Cancer</option>
          <option value="Capricorn">Capricorn</option>
          <option value="Gemini">Gemini</option>
          <option value="Leo">Leo</option>
          <option value="Libra">Libra</option>
          <option value="Pisces">Pisces</option>
          <option value="Sagittarius">Sagitarrius</option>
          <option value="Scorpio">Scorpio</option>
          <option value="Tarus">Taurus</option>
          <option value="Virgo">Virgo</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="rising" style="color: #4caf50ff">Rising</label>
        <br>
        <select name="rising" class="form-control-rising" id="rising">
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Your Rising</option>
          <option value="Aquarius">Aquarius</option>
          <option value="Aries">Aries</option>
          <option value="Cancer">Cancer</option>
          <option value="Capricorn">Capricorn</option>
          <option value="Gemini">Gemini</option>
          <option value="Leo">Leo</option>
          <option value="Libra">Libra</option>
          <option value="Pisces">Pisces</option>
          <option value="Sagittarius">Sagitarrius</option>
          <option value="Scorpio">Scorpio</option>
          <option value="Tarus">Taurus</option>
          <option value="Virgo">Virgo</option>
        </select> 
        <br>
        <label style="color: #6a1b9aff;">Search</label>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Find My Twin" id="but" onclick="text()" />
        <hr>
        <p id="resulttext"></p>
        <p id="resulttable"></p>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
```

So for example, if someone selected `sun Aquarius`, `moon Aries`, and `rising Cancer` then when they hit the button, I would want it to return the full table where `C = sun`, `D = moon`, and `E = rising`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out yesterday. I added this to my head's script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var visualization;
    function drawVisualization() {
      // This saves the user's selected options from the selects in the body
      var sun = $('#sun').find(":selected").text();
      var moon = $('#moon').find(":selected").text();
      var rising = $('#rising').find(":selected").text();

      //How to query from a Google Sheets doc via URL
      var query = new google.visualization.Query(
          '//docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f5WBP_vizrCw27fSA6yc0EEN_twmdC-PoXZhm_PSNH0/edit?usp=sharing');

      // The SELECT query where I search based on the user input variables, also created labels for the table headers
      query.setQuery("SELECT B,C,D,E WHERE C = '"+sun+"' AND D = '"+moon+"' AND E = '"+rising+"' ORDER BY B LABEL B 'Instagram', C 'Sun', D 'Moon', E ' Rising'");

      // Send the query with a callback function.
      query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    }

    function handleQueryResponse(response) {
      if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      }

      var data = response.getDataTable();
      visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('visualization'));
      visualization.draw(data, {width: '500px'});      
    }
    </script>
```

And this part here is the little snippet from the body of the HTML that triggers the above function

```
<input type="button" value="Find My Twin" id="but" onclick="drawVisualization()" />
<hr>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't yet started working with the Google Sheets API. You're going to need access to that before you can continue with fetching data from Sheets. The documentation for the API is here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/.

Setup instructions: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js
Reading values from a sheet: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading

The easiest method for you is probably to pull the entire sheet of data, then filter it on your end.

As an example, using the guide above would return something like this:

```
{
  "range": "Sheet1!A1:D5",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
    ["_st.x_r","Aquarius","Aquarius","Aquarius"],
    ["Placlara","Aquarius","Aquarius","Aquarius"],
    ["@sassybre2","Aquarius","Aquarius","Aquarius"],
    ["awitchydisco","Aquarius","Aquarius","Aries"],
    ["ellelleff","Aquarius","Aquarius","Cancer"],
    ["hunter.frisk","Aquarius","Aquarius","Cancer"],
    ...
  ],
}
```

You could then filter the get the values with `response.values` and filter them with something like `response.values.filter(value => value[1] == 'sun' && value[2] == 'moon' && value[3] = 'rising'`.

Comment: Does this account for an actively updating sheet? I get a few hundred new entries a week. Also, other possible solutions I thought about was to get the active sheet, and to use setQuery with its WHERE clause populated with the user's selected options. Could that work? Or are you saying this table method would be the fastest performing?

Comment: Yes, this would definitely account for an active sheet, as you'd be running the code client side, meaning that the sheet would be re-fetched for each user. I'm not sure what you mean by the 'active' sheet. This context makes sense from a Google Apps Script, but from Google Sites there is no active sheet in play, so you'd have to select with the sheet ID.

Comment: Also I'm not sure what you mean by `setQuery`; that's not part of the Sheets API. Is that part of another library?

Comment: Right, setQuery is a method of the google.visualization.Query class

Comment: It looks like the Visualization API's Query class could fully replace the Sheets API, so I wouldn't use both. Which one you choose depends on your work; if you're also going to be making visualizations, I'd use the Visualization API. If there's any chance you'll want to _write_ data to Sheets, you'll need the Sheets API. For fetching, they both work so it's up to you.

Comment: Personally, I feel like the Sheets API is simpler so I'd probably use that one, but the Visualization API is probably faster because it's transferring less data.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Ian. I think I'll keep trying with the Visualization API especially since I'm up to about 5,000 rows and want the search to be quick. Only queries, no edits